# What is the reason for using non-standard harp pedal notation?

Tags: notation, harp

According to [this page](http://harpnotation.com/the-harp/pedal-mechanism/notating-pedal-changes/), harp pedals are notated as

D C B E F G A.

In the score for [Holst's Planets - 7. Neptune](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/6/69/IMSLP15439-Neptune.pdf), the order

Cb D# Eb G# Ab B F#

was used. Is there a specific reason for this non-standard notation?

Comment: I'm very interested to hear from someone who knows (I don't, even though my daughter is learning harp!). I wonder, in particular, whether scordatura is involved? It's striking that three pairs of enharmonic equivalents are used, D#/Eb, G#/Ab, and Cb/B (note, you might want to edit your question to show this). The opening notes show why: the harpist alternates between two chords that are enharmonically equivalent, G# B D# and Ab Cb Eb, giving the effect of a rapid tremolo on a single pitch. I wonder whether they have to deviate from the standard tuning to accomplish this? Not sure.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a different kind of harp might have been used. Or maybe a translation/transcription error?

Comment: This may be a age related thing.  Your first link refers to a recently written document but that score is about a hundred years old.  Your first document also insists that the pedal markings are NEVER in the middle of the staves - but look where they are in the score.

Comment: I think your question is clear when looking at this specific page http://harpnotation.com/the-harp/pedal-mechanism/pedal-diagrams/

Comment: @JimM Pedal marks go above or below the grand staff in the part, but inside the grand staff (or even omitted entirely) in the full score to be more space efficient.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the pedal order is not consistent throughout the piece.

Comment: @ToddWilcox — the pedal marks are appearing inside the grand staff _even in the part_ for this piece.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace You're right. But what's strange is it's **only** for "Neptune", not for any of the other sections. The one thought is that it's a pocket score. I have a couple small format study scores and even the parts are small. Perhaps they needed to save space in both the full score and the parts. Also, perhaps the order of the pedals wasn't standardized in 1921 the way it is today.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my Walter Piston *Orchestration* book...

[image]

...the pedal notation can be given as scale degrees, letters grouped by the left/right pedal positions, or graphically as black marks on, above, or below a line.

Looks like Holst opted for the scale ordering.

Comment: How does that account for the F being last?

Comment: I edited my answer to take out the "alphabetical/scale order", that was my wording, not Piston's. The F being last doesn't really matter, the pedaling is clear: set F to sharp. The letter order is odd, but you can still see the settings.

Comment: My read of the question is that it’s asking *why* the pedal order is odd. This doesn’t seem to be a complete reason why, because it doesn’t offer an explanation for why the F is listed last.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But maybe there isn't a reason. If there isn't a requirement to indicate pedals in the first place, if given, why assume they must be in a particular order?

Comment: Holst found he'd missed the F setting and so put it at the end, and his editor didn't notice?